# Angular2fire "export declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I tried to install Angular2fire in my project, during the npm install I had the error:

> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.1.2
>
> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.1.2

And in the Angular2fire, they have:
"@angular/core": "^2.0.0"

And in my app modules:

> AngularFireModule.initializeApp({})

With the error:

> "export declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Do I need to downgrade my app ?

Thank you very much with your help.

Comment: Can you paste your module file ?

Comment: Sure.
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppCommonModule.forRoot(),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    ],

Comment: And is your firebase config looking like this : export const firebaseConfig = {...} and is it above the @NgModule ?

Comment: It looks like webpack doesn't compile the .d.ts file for this library